# How to boxplot data with 99% dominated by zeros in plotly?

Tags: r, plotly

I have a dataset of number of virus people on public transport might get from breathing or touching surfaces. Most of the doses are 0. How can I plot these data in a meaningful way in plotly?

```
#Some similar data
install.packages("wakefield") #For random Yes/No

isZero = rbinom(n = 3000, size = 1, prob = 0.99)
data = ifelse(isZero==1, 0, rlnorm(sum(isZero==0), meanlog = 0, sdlog = 1))
df<-data.frame(variable=rep(c("Air", "Fomite", "Close Range"), each=1000), 
               value=data, 
               Mask=wakefield::answer(3000, x = c("No", "Yes"), prob = NULL, name = "Mask"))

#Add a few extra outliers
df$value[500:510]=runif(n=10,min=10,max=14)
df$value[1500:1510]=runif(n=10,min=10,max=14)
df$value[2500:2510]=runif(n=10,min=10,max=14)

#Plotl in R plotly

fig <- df%>% plot_ly(alpha = 0.6, type="box")
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(x = ~log10(value[a$Mask == 'Yes']), 
                         y= ~variable[a$Mask == 'Yes'], legendgroup = 'Yes',
                         scalegroup = 'Yes',
                         name = 'Yes')
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(x = ~log10(value[a$Mask == 'No']), 
                         y= ~variable[a$Mask == 'No'],   legendgroup = 'No',
                         scalegroup = 'No',
                         name = 'No' )

fig <- fig %>%
  layout(
    yaxis = list(
      zeroline = F
    ),
    boxmode = 'group'
  )
```

[image]

Comment: In this case, a boxplot might not be the best visualization of the data. Instead, consider a box plot of the _count_ of different categories, e.g. no exposure, some exposure, great exposure.

Comment: Interesting. I think I would need to define what "some exposure" or "great exposure" means quantitatively. What do you think?

Comment: Very much so yes. Or you need to choose a different way of visualizing your specific data, in order for it to make sense. This should be rooted in your hypothesis.